# Override Java methods in Python using Pyjnius

Tags: java, python, pyjnius

I would like to use Pyjnius to create a Python class that extends a Java class and overrides some of its methods.

Specifically, these Java classes:

```
public class A {

    public void test_method() {
        System.out.println("In parent test_method!!!");
    }

    public static void run(A a) {
        System.out.println("Running...");
        a.test_method();
    }

}
```

and

```
public class B extends A {

    public void test_method() {
        System.out.println("test method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A.run(new B());
    }
}
```

When I run that I see:

```
Running...
test method
```

How do I re-implement `B` in Python using Pyjnius?

This is my attempt:

```
import jnius_config
jnius_config.set_classpath('jars/testClasses.jar')

from jnius import autoclass, PythonJavaClass, JavaClass, MetaJavaClass, java_method

A = autoclass('test.pyjnius.A')


class B(A):
    __javaclass__ = 'test/pyjnius/A'

    @java_method('()Z')
    def test_method(self):
        print("test method")


A.run(B())
```

When I run the Python version I see this:

```
Running...
In parent test_method!!!
```

It isn't properly overriding `test_method`. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is that what I am trying to do is not possible. The JVM cannot call the a method implemented in a Python subclass because it doesn't even know it exists.

The workaround is to implement the `run` method in class `B`, but make accommodations for the subclass's method. Something like this:

```
class B(A):
    __javaclass__ = 'test/pyjnius/A'

    @java_method('()Z')
    def test_method(self):
        print("test method")

    def run(self):
        A.runPart1(self)
        self.test_method()
        A.runPart2(self)
```

With `runPart1` and `runPart2` implemented in Java in a modified version of class `A`.